# Why is the Windows filesystem mounted on WSL with noexec and nodev options?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

*I'm asking this question because I'm curious and I want to understand WSL better.*

My environment is Windows 11, using WSL 2 running Ubuntu. I'm learning container fundamentals and I've encountered an interesting error when running [debootstrap](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html).

When I run it in the mounted Windows filesystem (`/mnt/c/`):

```
user@laptop:/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop$ sudo debootstrap --arch amd64 jammy container_fs http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I get the following error:

```
mknod: /mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs/test-dev-null: Operation not supported
E: Cannot install into target '/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs' mounted with noexec or nodev
```

I tried to remount `/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs` with `exec` and `dev` options.

```
user@laptop:/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop$ sudo mount -o remount,exec,dev /mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs
```

Output:

```
mount: /mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

It was at this point that I tried running debootstrap on `/home/user/` and it worked without any issues.

Comment: If you run the command in Ubuntu directory, does it work ?

Comment: @Philippe the command works fine when I run it in Ubuntu directory (`/home/user/`)

Comment: Is that directory a mountpoint? Probably not. `/mnt/c` probably is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the Windows filesystem mounted on WSL with noexec and nodev options?

The error message you are receiving is a bit misleading.  It's actually *not* mounted with either of those options, as you can confirm with:

```
mount | grep '/mnt/c'
```

> `drvfs on /mnt/c type 9p (rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=C:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio)`

---

> I tried to remount `/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs` with `exec` and `dev` options.
>
> ...
>
> `mount: /mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs: mount point not mounted or bad option.`

*That* error is because `/mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs` isn't a mountpoint.  The *mountpoint* is `/mnt/c`.  The following will complete successfully:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec,dev /mnt/c
```

However, it won't solve your problem.

---

Keep in mind that the error says `noexec` **or** `nodev`.

So let's break this down into two parts:

> `noexec`

As mentioned above, the filesystem actually *is* mounted with the `exec` privilege, and you *can* run executables from that drive.  This is why you can run Windows executables such as `notepad.exe`, `powershell.exe`, and `code` from the Windows drive.  You can test the counter-example with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,noexec,dev /mnt/c/
notepad.exe
```

You'll receive a `Permission denied` until you remount with `exec`.

---

> `nodev`

For this, it's important to look at the first part of the error from `debootstrap`:

```
mknod: /mnt/c/Users/user/workshop/container_fs/test-dev-null: Operation not supported
```

This is likely because the Windows filesystem and its share under WSL2 isn't fully POSIX compliant.

WSL2 provides access to Windows drives through the Plan 9 (9P) network filesystem.  As far as I can tell, 9P doesn't support `mknod`.  According to [this comment](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/bsd-mac-os-x-hurd-others/1106040-microsoft-begins-rolling-out-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/page3#post1106298) that I found, even the Linux version of 9P doesn't (or at least didn't 3-4 years ago) support `mknod`.

The ext4 filesystem on the virtual SDD being used for the WSL2 distribution itself, however, is fully POSIX compliant, which is why the `debootstrap` works there.

Comment: This answers my question, comprehensively.